# No such file or directory error using pyinstaller and scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, pyinstaller

I have a python script that uses scrapy and I want to make it into an exe file using pyinstaller. The exe file is generated without any error but when I open it an error occurs.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...\\scrapy\\VERSION'
```

I have tried reinstalling scrapy but that did not help. I am using windows 10 with python3

Answer (score 12):

**Full Disclosure: This is a repost of my answer to a duplicate, similar question. I am just putting it here for visiblity. This genuinely answers the question asked; so it is relevant.**

You did not use Pyinstaller properly when you had built your stand-alone program. Here is a short, layman's description of how Pyinstaller works: Pyinstaller bundles the Python interpreter, necessary DLLs (for Windows), your project's source code, and ***all the modules it can find*** into a folder or self-extracting executable. Pyinstaller does not include modules or files it cannot find in the final .exe (Windows), .app (macOS), folder, etc. that results when you run Pyinstaller.

So, here is what happened:

```bash
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEIbxALM3/scrapy/VERSION'
```

You ran your frozen/stand-alone program. As soon as you did this, your program was 'extracted' to a new, temporary folder on your computer `/temp/_MEIbxALM3/`. This folder contains the Python interpreter, your program's source code, and the modules Pyinstaller managed to find (plus a couple other necessary files).

The Scrapy module is more than just a module. It is an entire framework. It has its own plain text files (besides Python files) that it uses. And, it imports a lot of modules itself.

The Scrapy framework especially does not get along with Pyinstaller because it uses many methods to import modules that Pyinstaller cannot 'see'. Also, Pyinstaller basically makes no attempt to include files in the final build that are not .py files *unless you tell it to*.

**So, what *really* happened?**

The text file 'VERSION' that exists in the 'normal' scrapy module on your computer (that you had installed with pip or pipenv) was not included in the copycat scrapy module in the build of your program. Scrapy needs this file; Python is giving you the `FileNotFoundError` because it simply was never included. So, you have to include the file in the build of your program with Pyinstaller.

**How do you tell Pyinstaller where to find modules and files?**

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49092020/9347694) says to just copy the missing files from where they are installed on your computer into your build folder spit out from Pyinstaller. This does work. But, there is a better way and Pyinstaller can do more of the work for you (preventing further `ImportError`s and `FileNotFoundError`s you may get). See below:

**`build.spec` Files are Your Friend**

`spec` files are just Python files that Pyinstaller uses like a configuration file to tell it how to build your program. Read more about them [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html). Below is an example of a real `build.spec` file I used recently to build a Scrapy program with a GUI for Windows (my project's name is **B.O.T. Bot**):

```python
import gooey
gooey_root = os.path.dirname(gooey.__file__)
gooey_languages = Tree(os.path.join(gooey_root, 'languages'), prefix = 'gooey/languages')
gooey_images = Tree(os.path.join(gooey_root, 'images'), prefix = 'gooey/images')
a = Analysis(['botbotgui.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Colton\\.virtualenvs\\bot-bot-JBkeVQQB\\Scripts', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Redist\\ucrt\\DLLs\\x86'],
             hiddenimports=['botbot.spiders.spider'],
             hookspath=['.\\hooks\\'],
             runtime_hooks=None,
             datas=[('.\\spiders\\','.\\spiders\\'), ('.\\settings.py','.'),
                    ('.\\scrapy.cfg','.'), ('.\\items.py','.'), ('.\\itemloaders.py','.'),
                    ('.\\middlewares.py','.'), ('.\\pipelines.py','.')
                   ]
             )
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

options = [('u', None, 'OPTION'), ('u', None, 'OPTION'), ('u', None, 'OPTION')]

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          options,
          gooey_languages, # Add them in to collected files
          gooey_images, # Same here.
          name='BOT_Bot_GUI',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
          windowed=True,
          icon=os.path.join(gooey_root, 'images', 'program_icon.ico'))

#coll = COLLECT(exe,
    #a.binaries,
    #a.zipfiles,
    #a.datas,
    #options,
    #gooey_languages, # Add them in to collected files
    #gooey_images, # Same here.
    #name='BOT_Bot_GUI',
    #debug=False,
    #strip=False,
    #upx=True,
    #console=False,
    #windowed=True,
    #icon=os.path.join(gooey_root, 'images', 'program_icon.ico'))
```

Uncomment the last region if you want to build a folder instead of a stand-alone `.exe`. This is a configuration file specific to my computer and project structure. So in your file, you would have to change a few things (for example `pathex` to tell Pyinstaller where to find DLLs on Windows 10. But, the premise is the same.

My project directory looks like this:

```
botbotgui.py  botbot.py  hooks  images  __init__.py  itemloaders.py  items.py  middlewares.py  pipelines.py  __pycache__  scrapy.cfg  settings.py  spiders
```

Pay special attention to the `hooks/` directory. Using hooks will save you from a lot of headaches down the road. Read more about Pyinstaller's hooks feature [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html). In the `hooks/` directory there is a hook file for Scrapy. This will tell Pyinstaller to include many modules and files *it would have otherwise missed* if you did not use a `.spec` file. **This is the most important thing I have wrote here so far.** If you do not do this step, you will keep getting `ImportError`s every time you try to run a Scrapy program built using Pyinstaller. Scrapy imports MANY modules that Pyinstaller misses.

**`hook-scrapy.py` (Note: Your hook file must be named just like this.):**

```python
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules, collect_data_files

# This collects all dynamically imported scrapy modules and data files.
hiddenimports = (collect_submodules('scrapy') +
                 collect_submodules('scrapy.pipelines') +
                 collect_submodules('scrapy.extensions') +
                 collect_submodules('scrapy.utils')
)
datas = collect_data_files('scrapy')
```

After you finished writing a proper `build.spec` file, all you need to do is run Pyinstaller like this in your shell prompt:

```
pyinstaller build.spec
```

Pyinstaller should then spit out a proper build of your program that should work. Problem solved.

Comment: Great explanation @coltoneakins! I previously used pyinstaller along with the mne signal analysis package. To the spec file, I had to add a line ```datas=[background.png]``` which loaded a required image. The mne developers added a feature that resulted in a file not found error when I tried to run my app at the command line.. I removed the above ```datas``` and replaced it with```datas=collect_data_files('mne')``` and things worked! What I don't understand is how the image is being found. Could it be because it's inside a directory I Iisted in pathex? How do I concatenate the two datas?

Comment: @fishbacp - To "concatenate the two datas", you could do two different approaches: 1) just do `datas=[background.png],collect_data_files('mne')` or 2) create your own hook file for mne. Similar to `hook-scrapy.py` above, you would create `hook-mne.py` where you can just have: 

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

data= collect_data_files('mne')

```
Then, you could include both this new hook file and your 'normal' `data=[background.png]` in your spec file.

Comment: Nice. Should the bracket after .png be there or immediately after 'mne')?

Comment: I saw that ```collect._data_files('mne')``` is a long list of ordered pairs. Could I use the append command? Perhaps something like, ```datas.append(something)```, where "something" is an ordered pair containing background.png? If so, it's not clear to me what the ordered pair would be.

Comment: @fishbacp - I am not actually sure if the syntax for the #1 approach I mentioned above is actually `data=[background.png],collect_data_files('mne')`--I think pyinstaller just expects a list here. So, yes you can probably concatinate the list returned by `collect_data_files` and your one list of the background.png image.

Answer (score 1):

You can find that file in scrapy package. Go to this **Path: Python/Lib/site-packages/scrapy**, and you will find that file. Here are the steps that you are gonna do next:

1. Go to the directory where your exe file is, and create a folder named scrapy.
2. Copy **VERSION** and **mime.types** from the Path above. (If you don't copy **mime.types**, there will just be another no such file error. I'm just saving your time)
3. Paste those two files to the scrapy folder you created in step 1.
4. Now open your exe file. If **No Module Error** shows up, you just need to import the corresponding module in the file to which you want to use Pyinstaller.

Good luck. :)