# How can I create a single executable file in Windows 10 with Scrapy and PyInstaller?

Tags: python, scrapy, pyinstaller

I have created a Scrapy spider and successfully converted to a Windows executable using PyInstaller with a disc folder.

In order to do that, I have to make some slight changes in the Scrapy site-packages and add those packages in the Windows disc folder. It works perfectly.

How can I make this into a single EXE file with the commented Scrapy packages from the disc folder?

I have already tried with *--OneFile* command in PyInstaller, but it shows the Scrapy error. Why?

Error:

> ImportError: No module named 'scrapy.spiderloader'

I am calling Scrapy from a script and spider details are passing inside crawl process() function. How can I tell PyInstaller to fetch my updated Scrapy package from a location?

Comment: have you tried pyinstaller's hiddenimport ?  For example:  --hidden-import=saidmodule.py

Comment: I have tried with hidden imports for package scrapy, from the command line as well as the .spec file. both show the same error.

Comment: What is a *"disc folder"*? Do you mean *"dist folder"* or *"dest folder"*? (*"dist"* may or may not be for *"distribution"* (or *"distributable"*?) and *"destination"*, respectively)

Answer (score 7):

A very similar issue is discussed in *[Python Scrapy conversion to EXE file using PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493828/python-scrapy-conversion-to-exe-file-using-pyinstaller/54600860#54600860)*.

Initially, I used the [`auto-py-to-exe`](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) package (which is actually a GUI for PyInstaller). 
I added following line to `auto-py-to-exe -> advanced settings -> hidden import`:

```
scrapy.spiderloader,scrapy.statscollectors,scrapy.logformatter,scrapy.extensions,scrapy.extensions.corestats,scrapy.extensions.corestats,scrapy.extensions.telnet,scrapy.extensions.memusage,scrapy.extensions.memdebug,scrapy.extensions.closespider,scrapy.extensions.feedexport,scrapy.extensions.logstats,scrapy.extensions.spiderstate,scrapy.extensions.throttle,scrapy.core.scheduler,scrapy.squeues,queuelib,scrapy.core.downloader,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats,scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache,scrapy.spidermiddlewares,scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror,scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite,scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer,scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength,scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth,scrapy.pipelines,scrapy.dupefilters,scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.datauri,scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.file,scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http,scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3,scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.ftp,scrapy.core.downloader.webclient,scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory
```

After that, the following command appeared in the last text box (don't forget to change path to your script):

```
pyinstaller -y -F --hidden-import scrapy.spiderloader --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter --hidden-import scrapy.extensions --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.corestats --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.corestats --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.telnet --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.memusage --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.memdebug --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.feedexport --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.logstats --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.spiderstate --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.throttle --hidden-import scrapy.core.scheduler --hidden-import scrapy.squeues --hidden-import queuelib --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache --hidden-import scrapy.spidermiddlewares --hidden-import scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror --hidden-import scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite --hidden-import scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer --hidden-import scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength --hidden-import scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth --hidden-import scrapy.pipelines --hidden-import scrapy.dupefilters --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.datauri --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.file --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3 --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.ftp --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader.webclient --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory "C:/path/script.py"
```

If after, this your command returns: `ImportError: No module named 'modulename'` - add missing module to hidden imports and repeat this process with new extended hidden imports. 
(I repeated this procedure 48 times in order to receive a working EXE file (and receive a list of submodules)!!)

**Update**

On Nov 12, 2019 (~ 6 month after I posted this answer ) pyinstaller added hooks that solved this specific import errors https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/4514/files

Contents of that pull request to pyinstaller pointing to this stack overflow question
[No such file or directory error using pyinstaller and scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085970/no-such-file-or-directory-error-using-pyinstaller-and-scrapy)

At this stage developers who will try to make exe from scrapy application - the most likely will have issue mentioned on
[Error after running .exe file originating from scrapy project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75308876/error-after-running-exe-file-originating-from-scrapy-project)
which is completely different question.

Comment: Those are some very long command lines (1490 and 2296 characters, respectively). Not all command line processors may be able to handle them. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: I made re-review of this and I found that contents of my answer.. are obsolete now. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using *--hidden imports* in the spec file.
PyInstaller doesn't support all second-level module imports in Scrapy.

Run the PyInstaller command. Just update the spec file with the below hidden import changes,

```
hiddenimports=['scrapy.spiderloader','scrapy.statscollectors','scrapy.logformatter','scrapy.extensions','scrapy.extensions.logstats', 'scrapy.extensions.corestats','scrapy.extensions.memusage','scrapy.extensions.feedexport','scrapy.extensions.memdebug', 'scrapy.extensions.closespider','scrapy.extensions.throttle','scrapy.extensions.telnet','scrapy.extensions.spiderstate', 'scrapy.core.scheduler','scrapy.core.downloader','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry','scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http', 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3','scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.ftp','scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.datauri', 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.file','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl','scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats','scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache', 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares','scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror','scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite','scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer', 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength','scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth','scrapy.pipelines','scrapy.dupefilters','queuelib', 'scrapy.squeues',]
```

It was fixed with 45 module import issues. Using *--onefile* helps to run the Scrapy project in a single executable.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Scrapy spider a Python script by following [the updated documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/practices.html)!

Follow the usual PyInstaller command to make the executable (make sure you are running it from inside your Scrapy project).

```
    pyinstaller --onefile filename.py
```