# Cannot run Scrapy Spider in .exe (Terminal opens and closes)

Tags: python, scrapy, exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

it's my first question on here, so I'll do my best:

I wrote a Scrapy Crawler in Python 3.6 and it works perfectly.

I've tried to put it in a .exe file so my client can run it from a Windows machine, without having Scrapy or Python installed.

I've managed to create .exe files using both, **PyInstaller** and **cx_Freeze**, but in both cases when I try to run the file on Windows, the terminal opens and closes immediately.

I guess my question is, if it's even possible to run a Scrapy Crawler as .exe and if so, how can I circumvent the terminal problem?

Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: If you start the .exe from a terminal, can you see any output that gives a hint of why it exists?

Comment: I haven't tried to run it from the terminal, just by clicking it (as seen in a few tutorials). Will try tomorrow and write back (it's late in Austria:). But, do you know if it's even possible to run a Scrapy Spider as .exe? And thanks, btw

Comment: Quick update: I started .exe from the terminal and got the same result (terminal opens and closes immediately), so any hints on how to solve this are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339170/939364?

Comment: Wow, thanks! No, I haven't seen this but it actually looks like it could work! Will report back as soon as I've tested it. Thanks again

Comment: I am not familiar with it. Try leaving a comment in that answer, maybe the author can help.