# How to convert python script to exe for running in mac using windows 7

Tags: python, scrapy, exe, py2exe

I have made scrapy script and it works fun! my client needs me to convert it to exe program I have done it before but for windows users not for mac so
***My question is*** there is a method to convert the script to exe?

Comment: I had the same issue. I figure with `pyinstaller`. But you have install python and add to the path to client' pc.

Comment: You can't. The tools that do this like `pyinstaller` cannot cross-compile. To bundle your Python program into an executable that will run on a Mac, you need a Mac.

Comment: thanks for the quick replying

Comment: Murat Demir  can you explain more, please

Comment: @BoarGules could be right I have been using Mac I had 3 spiders and my partner want to run them every day manually. I use pyinstaller everything goes well with mac

Comment: have you tried py2bin?

Comment: @ Ricardo  No I will search about it

Comment: @Ricardo how to use it from windows

Comment: will need an virtrual machine or emulator of some sort

Comment: @AhmedEllban . Usage of pyinstaller with [hidden import can solve your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339170/10884791)